# Understanding results with valgrind

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

For the following code I have the following defintion:

```
typedef struct string {char* data; int length;} string;
```

If I run the following code with valgrind, I got conditional jump or move depends on unitinialized value and seg. fault:

```
string* s = (string*) malloc(sizeof(string));
strcpy("Hello", s->data);
free(s);
```

First of all, I can't understand why I got above errors.
I thought if I add to that code `free(s->data)` it will freed memory but program will run ok.

How I think:
I know `sizeof(string)` equal to 4(pointer to char) + 4(int) = 8.
then we allocate 8 bits for s.
strcpy will copy the string into data but I got a problem here. why?

Comment: "1(pointer to char)"? Typical pointer size on modern PC is 4 or 8. What is your environment? Also I guess the allocation should be 5 bytes, not 5 bits.

Comment: `strcpy("Hello", s->data);`? you sure?

Comment: @MikeCAT, you right. it is 4 bits. I have then 8 bits

Comment: `First of all, I can't understand why I got above error`.. start by reading the [man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html)

Comment: Buffer allocated via `malloc()` is uninitialized. `s->data` is also uninitialized.

Comment: @MikeCAT, you right, then it has garbage. so as I understood it, our stack will be {H,e,l,l,o,\0, *, *} * is garbage. why is a problem? I have confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

```
string* s = (string*) malloc(sizeof(string));
```

which should better be

```
string* s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
```

allocates memory for `s->data`, but does not make `s->data` point to any valid memory location. If you want to make use of the memory location, you need to make sure that it points to a valid memory location. For example: you'd need to `malloc()` for `s->data` seperately.

That said, the [syntax for `strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) says, it's `strcpy(dest, source)`, so in your case

```
strcpy("Hello", s->data);
```

attempts to

- read from an unitilized memory location
- write into a string literal

either of which invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should write

```
strcpy(s->data, "Hello");
```

after ensuring `s->data` is a valid destination.

Comment: And `s->data` is still not initialized.

Comment: `string* s = (string*) malloc(sizeof(string));` is correct, but then add:

Comment: `s->data= maloc(sizeof("hello"));`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Certainly the first approach, but given the unknown usage, we may need more memory - just saying.